# Windows 10 Image Backup to Thumb Drive

Tags: backup, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

Fellow Forum Members,

How does one create a System Image of an entire Windows10 installation onto a 128GB thumb drive?  I tried doing it through the Windows 10 System Image tool but it sees a thumb drive as an invalid storage device. Then I Googled the subject and learned I need to convert the thumb drive to a Local Disk. Can anyone out there recommend the best app to use to convert a thumb drive to a Local Disk?

Another option I learned about is to backup to a network location and convert the thumb drive to a network drive. However, I am unable to find any info that will show me how to convert my thumb drive to a network drive.

My goal is to install my thumb drive and transfer it over to my blank SSD drive if I ever have to rebuild it in the future.

Any info will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you should plug your thumb drive into another computer to confirm that your thumb drive is available. And if it is normal, there is something wrong with the Windows 10 system image tool. I recommend a perfect backup software - AOMEI Backupper which can create a system image of an entire Windows 10 installation. You can just download this freeware, install and launch it. Then you follow the wizard of System Backup function of AOMEI Backupper. What need to pay attention to is you must plug your thumb drive into your computer before launch AOMEI Backupper, just to confirming the device can be detected.

Comment: Just one thing for confirmation. While creating the system image in the thumb drive, does AOMEI delete existing files in the thumb drive or does it retain them?